# C# Monitor.Exit in Try/Catch

Tags: c#, multithreading, try-catch

I am troubleshooting old source code, and came across a statement like this:

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj))
{
    try
    {
        //does something
        if (failing_condition)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
            throw new Exception("Oops!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is crashing with a `System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.`

Is there a safe way to call `Monitor.Exit()` on both the failing condition and when normal execution finishes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do it in the finally block, its always runs even if an exception is thrown above. Also the catch section is unnecessary.

```
 if(Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj)) {
  try {
    //does something
    if(failing_condition) {      
      throw new Exception("Oops!");
    }
  }
  finally {
    Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
  }
}
```

Comment: `catch` block in this case is overriding the exception details, which can be intended here.